# Retrieve a list of Einstein Analytics dashboards via API

Tags: rest-api, einstein-analytics-dashboards

How do you get wave dashboards?

I tried googling for it and I found a trailblazer article saying you can SOQL query like: `SELECT ... FROM Dashboard`. But this always returned 0 results for me. So I'm guessing it wasn't for wave dashboards.

Any way to get at the very least a list of id's for einstein/wave/analytics dashboards?

Comment: This sounds like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you trying to accomplish? Please edit your question.

Comment: @identigral I want to make a lightning component that displays all my dashboards and links to their pages

Comment: [List Dashboards](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bi_dev_guide_rest.meta/bi_dev_guide_rest/bi_resources_dashboards.htm) via API can do that.

Comment: @identigral i've seen that link, but couldn't work out how I would do it, could you show an example please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you couldn't query an object via SOQL to retrieve the list of Einstein Analytics (EA) dashboards is that this information is stored in metadata. Redacted screenshot of one EA dashboard's metadata from [Workbench](https://workbench.developerforce.com/login.php):

[image]

You can [query Metadata](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_metadata_retrieve_deploy.htm) via native Apex calls but it doesn't support EA metadata types. Your next stop would be the [Metadata API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_intro.htm). Unfortunately using it is cumbersome. There's an Apex-friendly wrapper ([apex-mdapi](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi)) but it also doesn't support EA types. Therefore calling the [List Dashboards](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bi_dev_guide_rest.meta/bi_dev_guide_rest/bi_resources_dashboards.htm) REST API is your best option.

The List Dashboards REST API returns *a lot* of information. Here's a heavily redacted response that shows a few relevant fields of a single dashboard

```js
{
   "dashboards": [
      {
         "id": "0FK4W000000gJwPWAU",
         "label": "Accounts",
         "name": "Accounts_Dashboard",
         "url": "/services/data/v49.0/wave/dashboards/0FK4W000000gJwPWAU"
      }
   ]
}
```

Calling the API and reading the response in Apex:

```java
Http client = new Http();
HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
request.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + UserInfo.getSessionId());
request.setEndPoint(URL.getOrgDomainUrl().toExternalForm() + '/services/data/v49.0/wave/dashboards');
request.setMethod('GET');
HttpResponse response = client.send(request);

WaveDashboards allBoards = WaveDashboards.parse(response.getBody());
for (Dashboard d : allBoards.dashboards) {
  System.debug('Dashboard: ' + d);
}

public class WaveDashboards {

    public class Dashboard {
        public String id;
        public String label;
        public String name;
        public String url;
    }

    public List<Dashboard> dashboards;

    
    public static WaveDashboards parse(String json) {
        return (WaveDashboards) System.JSON.deserialize(json, WaveDashboards.class);
    }
}
```

Note: the sample code above performs no error checking and assumes the returned list of dashboards isn't too long so as not to require pagination.